# lists are not clickable in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of destination name which should be clickable and show some result but my lists are not clickable .I have tried just writing console.log in the click event function but nothing is traced in console too.

**Destination-list**

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var Destination = require('./Destination.js.jsx');

var DestinationsList = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    React.addons.PureRenderMixin
  ],
  onDestinationClick: function(destination) {
    console.log('destination clicked');
    console.log(destination);
    this.props.onDestinationClick(destination);
  },
  renderDestinations: function() {
    var _self = this;
    var selectedDestination = _self.props.selectedDestination;
    return this.props.destinations.map(function(destination, idx) {
      var name = destination.name;
      var slug = destination.slug;
      var image = destination.image;
      return <Destination destination={destination} selectedDestination={selectedDestination} onDestinationClick={_self.onDestinationClick} key={'destination-' + slug}/>
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='destinations-list'>
        <div className='destinations-list-inner'>
          {this.renderDestinations()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = DestinationsList;
```

**Destination**

```
var Destination = React.createClass({
  mixins: [
    React.addons.PureRenderMixin
  ],
  onDestinationNameClick: function(event) {
    console.log('event triggered',event);
    this.props.onDestinationClick(this.props.destination);
  },
  render: function() {
    var classes = this.props.selectedDestination === this.props.destination.slug ? 'destination selected' : 'destination';
    return (
      <div className={classes}>
        <div className='destination-inner'>
          <div className='destination-name' onClick={this.onDestinationNameClick}>{this.props.destination.name}</div> // not clickable
        </div>
      </div>
   );
  }
})


module.exports = Destination;
```

Comment: Pasted your example in jsBin, and it correctly logs the destination in the console.

Comment: pasted?Did you paste?

Comment: Yes: http://jsbin.com/jipobeciho/edit?js,console,output